# Should a positive Orr negative tag question be used with the phrase “only a few"?

Tags: tag-questions

I'd like to know whether a positive or negative tag should be used in a sentence with "only a few":

> There were **only a few** tourists there, were / weren't there?

Note that I'm talking about ordinary tags, not same-way tags.

Comment: If by "ordinary tag" you mean a tag appended to a "rhetorical question" (where speaker simply expects you to confirm that his "statement framed as a question" is in fact true), then it's *There were only a few, **weren't there**?, There's only one, **isn't there**?*, You're only human, **aren't you**?* But suppose you'd claimed there would only be a few tourists at this charming little beach you've just driven out to, but when you got there it was chockful of tourists (and the Germans had already got ***all*** the sunbeds! :) Then it's "sarcastic" *Only a **few** tourists, **were there**?*

Comment: Do you think "only a few" means "not many"? Many ESL/EFL teachers say it's therefore negative. If it's negative, then a positive tag is expected. However, it seems to me this expectation is not borne out.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the meaning of "negative" in this context. A "few" just means a small number. What would you think if the question had used an explicit value for that small number, as in *There were only **two** tourists there, were[/n't] there?*

Comment: Well, "a few" and "only a few" are treated differently in textbooks, the former being positive.

Comment: I think FumbleFingers' point is that "there were only a few" is not negative, because it's still stating that there were tourists there.  "There were **no** tourists" is negative.

Comment: How about "there are few tourists"? Is it negative or positive for the sake of tag question formation?

Comment: Here's a comment I found: "Americans use “only a few” and “very few” interchangeably. I would consider them to mean the same thing." https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/149033

Comment: Having thought it through a bit more, all I can say is that *some* "**There are**" assertions that include both ***only*** and ***few*** don't readily accept a tag question in the first place. But if you *can* idiomatically add a tag question to the assertion, it would always be in the negated form ***aren't there**?*, because tag questions always reverse the "positivity" of the preceding ***verb*** (which in this case is ***there are***, not ***there aren't***).

Comment: Thank you. Which question tag would you use in "There were **few** tourists on the beach"?